# Random number not updating in SetInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random, setinterval

I've tried a few different approaches to this found on SO but just cant seem to get it to work.

I'm trying to update the randomly selected item in an array, in a setInterval function, but the random number is not changing.

It is randomly chosen on first load, but then it doesn't update after the fact, each time the function runs again.

This is all using the lazylinepainter plugin: https://github.com/camoconnell/lazy-line-painter

```
var pathArray = [pathOne,pathTwo,pathThree,pathFour,pathFive,pathSix],
colors = ['#e51616','#0000FF','#FFFF00','#00FF00'],
drawBox = $('#drawing-box'),
svg = $('#drawing-box svg'),
svgPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");

function randomFrom(array) {
   return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

randomColor = randomFrom(colors);

var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 0 + 1));
console.log(i);

function Draw(){

   var drawLoop = setTimeout(function (){
                    $('#drawing-box svg path').animate({'opacity':0},300);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#drawing-box svg path').remove();
                        drawBox.lazylinepainter('paint');
                        console.log(pathArray[i]);
                    },350);
                },5500);

   var drawFunc = drawBox.lazylinepainter({
                "svgData": pathArray[i],
                "strokeColor": randomColor,
                "strokeWidth": 5,
                "responsive": true,
                "onComplete": drawLoop
            });

   drawFunc.lazylinepainter('paint')
};

setInterval(function(){
   Draw();
},6000);
```

Here it is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmrx8x2h/1/) —————

Rerun the fiddle over and over to see the different paths chosen at random (since its not updating otherwise).

Hopefully that snippet is clear, was still trying a few different things in there.

The ultimate goal is to have that line draw a randomly chosen item from the pathArray (pathOne, pathTwo, pathThree, etc. etc.) with each interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you are calling the actual function only once and then assigning it to `randomColor` which gets used over and over.

What you should do instead is call it where it is needed:

```
var drawFunc = drawBox.lazylinepainter({
            "svgData": pathArray[i],
            "strokeColor": randomFrom(colors),
            "strokeWidth": 5,
            "responsive": true,
            "onComplete": drawLoop
        });
```

That way you get a fresh one every time.

Comment: Well I'm trying two diff approaches between getting a random color (randomColor) and getting a random path (pathArray).

I thought if I called them within the Draw function they would update, but seems not... Should it all be wrapped in the Draw function?

Comment: In both cases you are calling the `Math.random()` outside of the `Draw()` function, thus it gets called once when the page starts up and never again. So you have to call it within the function.

Comment: Ahhhhh okay, I've updated the code by including the Math.random() function inside of the interval.
I'm writing the random #'s to console.log, and they're definitely updating now, but the drawn line itself isn't changing at all... Any idea why this may be?

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmrx8x2h/2/

Comment: Unfortunatley I don't have too much time to get into this in a lot of detail, but it seems like you have to somehow `destroy` and then recreate the plugin before you can have it draw in a different way.